# Does Azure Caching (Preview) preserve state across deployments?

Tags: caching, azure, session-state

Suppose I have some roles with co-located caching enabled, then I do a deploy and a VIP swap. Is the state preserved across the swap? I need session state for my Web Roles to be preserved over a deployment to Staging and then a VIP swap.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Azure Cache (Preview)**  utilizes your available role instances, you will lose state when you perform a VIP swap between environments. The only way around this is to use the default Azure Cache or publish directly to Production environment to avoid the VIP swap.

This state loss can be good and bad - I've seen cases where you change serialized objects managed within state from a recent publish and loading them back after a VIP swap causes the state load to crash - hence it is sometimes beneficial to remove the cache during a publish.

Comment: Is this still true?  It seems contradictory to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20966206/899530