# Azure Cache not persisting Session State across VIP swaps?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, azure

As a follow-up to this post: [Enabling co-located Session Caching in an Azure Cloud Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964697/enabling-co-located-session-caching-in-an-azure-cloud-service) - I'm trying to store session state in Azure Cache to persist sessions between VIP swaps.  Quoted from the answer:

> To fix this problem, I'd like you to try the new Cache Service
>   (Preview). In this way you create dedicate cache for your subscription
>   so that you can use them across cloud service deployments, virtual
>   machines and websites.

I've set up an Azure Cache (Preview) instance, used its endpoint and primary access key in my web.config, and deployed to my Azure Cloud Service Staging slot.

I then logged in using Forms auth, and redeployed to the same slot.  My credentials were persisted!  This was great to see.

But then I VIP swapped to Production, logged in the same way to the production instance, redeployed to Staging, VIP swapped again, and then refreshed, expecting to remain logged in, but it didn't work - my session was lost on both production and staging.

I've followed the instructions found here:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cache/net/how-to-in-role-cache/#getting-started-cache-role-instance

What could be causing this?  No exceptions are thrown - my access key works (tested by giving it a bogus one and getting an exception)... I'm not sure what's going on.  Config sections in web.config:

```
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <providers>
    <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" applicationName="AFCacheSessionState"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

And:

```
<dataCacheClient name="default">
      <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="mysite.cache.windows.net" />
      <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="false">
        <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="{my key}" />
      </securityProperties>
    </dataCacheClient>
```

As for timeout policy - I have it set to never expire with eviction enabled.  I'm one of a handful of users and the cache is storing cookies in 128MB of space, so I don't think it's related to expiry.

I also noticed that in the [docs](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cache/net/how-to-in-role-cache/#store-session), there is no entry for `applicationName` as I have above.  I tried removing it and re-testing, to no avail - my Prod session is still lost upon VIP swap.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

From a microsoft [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/c87e0cd6-a373-4435-8bf1-853e4f92d469/azure-cache-not-persisting-session-state-across-vip-swaps?forum=azurecache&prof=required):

> I was able to reproduce the issue. I am investigating.

Comment: Not 100% sure but could it be because ASP.Net Session Cookie became invalid as the domain changed when you did VIP swap from someguid.cloudapp.net (Staging) to yourwebsite.dom (Production)?

Comment: @GauravMantri - I hope not.  That would turn VIP swapping from "seamless updates" to "seamless frustrations" for the end users of my app, and wouldn't be much different from using standard colocated caching (right?).  To be clear - I was logged into mywebsite.com before the swap, and was hoping to remain logged in through the swap.

Comment: My bad :( For some reason I thought you logged into one environment, did a VIP swap and then expected to remain logged in into other environment as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forms authentication is not based on session state. It relies only on client-side cookies. Cookies are encrypted and validated with keys specified in [machineKey section of web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx). 
Default config is:

```
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps"  
            decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" 
            validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto" />
```

AutoGenerate means that each physical machine gets its own decryptionKey. Cookies generated by production VM will not be accepted by staging VM.

After VIP swap all cookies set by old production VM will be rejected by new production VM (ex-Staging VM), causing all users to be logged out.

You need to specify machineKey values explicitly to force Forms Auth to generate cookies that will be valid for both new and old production VMs (see [How To: Configure MachineKey, Web Farm Deployment Considerations section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx)).

Check this online tool for machineKey section generation: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey.

UPD: There is a related note in [Manage Deployments in Windows Azure/Managing ASP.NET machine keys for IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433027.aspx):

> Windows Azure automatically manages the ASP.NET machineKey for
>   services deployed using IIS. If you routinely use the VIP Swap
>   deployment strategy, you should manually configure the ASP.NET machine
>   keys.

Comment: Thanks Pasha.  Reading into this now... though I'm unsure about what exactly needs changing here.  Do I just need to generate a key and copy/paste the entry into web.config?  Is it that simple?

Comment: yes, you just have to generate a key and paste it to web.config. make sure that both production and staging will have the same key before test VIP swap.